# PostgreSQL CAST() giving unexpected results

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, cast, floating-point

I can't seem to figure out how this is rounding overflow digits. It is most definitely not any of:

- Round up if last digit is 5 or higher.
- Round to even if last digit is 5.
- Randomly round up or down if last digit is 5.

In fact, whatever logic it is using is definitely 1) deterministic, and 2) not [completely] based on the last digit being 5.

Some example inputs and output of:

```
CAST ('input' AS DOUBLE PRECISION);
```

Here, 'input' is not a variable, just a placeholder in this post for a literal numeric value with quotes around it, e.g. below in input column.

```
input                 output
34.55555555555595     34.5555555555559    *Obviously not rounding up
34.555555555555951    34.5555555555559    *Why not round up here?
34.5555555555559514   34.5555555555559    *Another unexpected round down
34.5555555555559515   34.555555555556     *Unexpected/seemingly inconsistent
34.55555555555595145  34.5555555555559
34.55555555555595146  34.5555555555559
34.55555555555595148  34.5555555555559
34.55555555555595149  34.555555555556     *Huh!?
```

Version: PostgreSQL 9.3.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

Comment: `CAST ('x' AS DOUBLE PRECISION);` will not work at all. It will result in the error: `invalid input syntax for type double precision: "x"` and will not return any values at all.

Comment: From [Postgres docs: Numeric types:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) *"double precision, 8 bytes, variable-precision, **inexact**, 15 decimal digits precision"* You are passing more than 15, even 18 digits to a type that can hold 15-16 digits. What did you expect?

Comment: From the same link: *"Inexact means that some values cannot be converted exactly to the internal format and are stored as approximations, so that storing and retrieving a value might show slight discrepancies."*

Comment: Necessary read: **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)**

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: I was using 'x' as a symbol within the post itself, not as a variable. I updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: ypercube™: I suppose that must be the only logical explanation, thanks. But since you asked "what did you expect", I expected a function named CAST() to do internal rounding before stuffing it into a float. For example, JavaScript parseFloat("34.55555555555595149").toPrecision(15) - which loses some significance, but gives expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment,

JavaScript parseFloat("34.55555555555595149").toPrecision(15)

the cast should be to the numeric datatype

```
CAST ('input' AS numeric(17,15))
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL